# My Appearance theme briefly changes itself

Tags: gnome, nautilus-elementary, themes

Recently my Gnome interface theme has occasionally changed itself on every few logins. On the times it does change as soon as I login I get a completely different theme set on my menu bar, icons, font, everything. It sets the grey accessibility one (I think)  but then after a few moments it changes itself back to the correct theme set in the Appearance menu.

However one after effect of this issue is that Nautilus become messed up. (Screenshot attached below:) This is the theme that gets randomly applied before changing back to my normal theme, but it sticks with Nautilus, unless I kill it and restart it.

[image: theme issue]

I don't know what I could of done to make this happen and it only started happening a few days ago.

Any help on this issue would be great! It's got me baffled!

Useful Info about my theme setup:

- Using Nautilus Elementary
- Faenza icon set
- Using Ambiance for menus and windows.
- Compiz Enabled
- Nvidia Graphics Card

Comment: Possibly, but my theme does come back after a few minutes without having to log back in again.

Answer (score 2):

Might be related to the following [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/574296) .

Comment: gnome-settings-daemon does seem to fit the issue. Is there any way of getting my theme completely back without logging out and in again?